# The one ring: Did Sauron create the Middle Earth world wide web?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

"One ring to rule them all..." when sauron creates the one ring does he create a "Network" among the rings of power ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. In what sense is the One Ring, or any of the other rings, like a computer or an operating system?

Comment: If I remember correctly, "the one ring to bind them all" refers only to the evil ring that Sauron has. The other rings (such as those possessed by Elves and other 'good' beings) are outside of Sauron's control, so he can only 'hack' his own ring atmost.

Comment: Also, I don't see any analogy with a world-wide-web. If you are referring to the fact that nazguls can detect the ring-wearer at any time, then that is not the only such thing. There are several other such magical communications happening throughout Tolkien's world.

Comment: I thought the WWW were the  Palantíri.

Comment: @PrahladYeri The One Ring did have influence over the other rings, including those possessed by the "good" races.  That's how he twisted the Kings of Men into the Nazgul, and such.  The Elven rings are, I think, the only ones outside of his control, through the powerful magic of the Elves.  (And maybe something about them being hidden from him during their creation?  I'm forgetting the specifics.)

Comment: YOu seem to be asking about the interconnectivity between the rings.  Might I sugggest: drop the connection to "the world wide web" entirely and just ask this question, describing what sort of connection you suspect they have, and asking what sort of connection really exists.  If you want to assume this means that Sauron created the internet in LotR, then that is your perogative.

Comment: the rings appeared to be isolated before sauron did the one ring to rule them all that it established a functional two way communication system (ring based) vs the palantheri (another system telecommunication) the  creation of the one ring either created a back door  network that superceeded function by individual operators of other rings as a worm or virus.. that the holders of the three lost function when the one ring became non functional in mt doom is a clue. when an guest operator  posessed the ring they didnt have access to the full function.

Comment: @origionalmerlin You could use a bit of editing, but this is the sort of information and clarification that should be edited into your post, not added as a comment.

Comment: Your question is clear and interesting for me

Comment: In regards to the title, if ANYONE in Middle Earth created a World Wide Web, it would have to be Ungoliant or Shelob.

Comment: @Omegacron puns ftw!

Answer (score 3):

It's a reasonable analogy, the many rings being magically connected (like a network) and the One serving as a malicious tool to hijack the network and control it.  (Although technically, the Elves would have made the "web" since they forged most of the many magic rings of the world, Sauron just would have been the hacker who took advantage of it.)

But given that the World Wide Web didn't exist in Tolkien's time, that's all it is: a modern analogy applied to the book.  Not anything inherent in the story, or in the writer's intention toward our understanding of the story.

Keep in mind, even the more mundane comparisons like "the Ring is nuclear power" or "the War of the Ring was World War II" were vigorously denied by Tolkien.  He wanted his stories to stand alone, applicable to other concepts (as you're doing here) but never simply taken as a re-telling or substitution.

Comment: concept is  the function of the one ring as a part of a system and the rings as being "networked by sauron would it be a worm a virus or just an hack?

Comment: well understood here about  tolkiens lotr and his views it being WWII .

Comment: When you're making the leap from "digital network of computers" to "magical network of rings," the distinctions between worm, virus, and hack become kind of meaningless. I'd call it a hack, since it isn't "installing" anything on the other rings, just hijacking the network to send "malicious code" (i.e. Sauron's influence) to all the "servers" (i.e. rings) on the network. I suppose the closest analogy would be that Sauron installed a [backdoor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing)) into the "ring network" that allowed him admin access across all devices. But this is all a stretch.

Comment: the mirror ogfgaladrael  chapter:  galadrael mentionoing ehe eye of sauron  that frodo saw in the mirror  and both sam and frodos expearience in using the ring "seeing and feeling the eye of sauron" gives a hint  of what the holders of  the three rings  had to deal with, we are not given information  of the seven , the nine, or the lesser rings